# Java Amazon S3 Post form

Tags: java, html, post, amazon-s3

I have problems with the s3 post form. I read though http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434/

I followed the whole tutorial:

```
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Storage {
    public static String awsAccessKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    public static String awsSecretKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    static String policy_document = "{\"expiration\": \"2013-01-01T00:00:00Z\","
            + "\"conditions\": ["
            + "{\"bucket\": \"kanta-assets\"},"
            + "[\"starts-with\", \"$key\", \"\"],"
            + "{\"acl\": \"public\"},"
            + "{\"success_action_redirect\": \"http://localhost/\"},"
            + "[\"starts-with\", \"$Content-Type\", \"\"],"
            + "[\"content-length-range\", 0, 1048576]" + "]" + "}";

    public static String getPolicy() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        return (new BASE64Encoder()).encode(policy_document.getBytes("UTF-8"))
                .replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll("\r", "");
    }

    public static String getSignature() throws InvalidKeyException,
            IllegalStateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Mac hmac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
        hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec(awsSecretKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA1"));
        return (new BASE64Encoder()).encode(
                hmac.doFinal(getPolicy().getBytes("UTF-8"))).replaceAll("\n",
                "");

    }

}
```

and my post form looks like this

```
<form action="https://kanta-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="hidden" name="key" value="uploads/${filename}">
      <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="@appconfig.Storage.awsAccessKey"> 
      <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public"> 
      <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://localhost/">
      <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="@appconfig.Storage.getPolicy()">
      <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="@appconfig.Storage.getSignature()">
      <input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg">
      <!-- Include any additional input fields here -->

      File to upload to S3: 
      <input name="file" type="file"> 
      <br> 
      <input type="submit" value="Upload File to S3"> 
    </form>
```

If I try to upload an jpeg image I get the following error:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
<Message/>
<ArgumentValue>public</ArgumentValue>
<ArgumentName>x-amz-acl</ArgumentName>
<RequestId>6679060CE7C84FA5</RequestId>
<HostId>
wSIzNZvFDFT7WNnUtBq9UY5WSN1ltN9dHErNk6L3v4ciZCSzwUgzTf1PgaFAJTWD
</HostId>
</Error>
```

I am pretty sure that my mistake is the key value in the policy `"[\"starts-with\", \"$key\", \"\"],"` I wasn't sure what this actually means.

> The rule for the object’s key name uses the prefix string “upload/”,
>   which means that the key value must always start with the upload/
>   subdirectory path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try giving the key as just the file name. (remove upload/)

Comment: What do you mean? I already have removed the upload/ to `"starts-with",""`

Comment: I meant in your post form hidden variable :- <input type="hidden" name="key" value="uploads/${filename}"> remove uploads/ and make it <input type="hidden" name="key" value="${filename}"> . if you have already done it, then well and good. I faced similar problem long back, and i vaguely remember there was a similar fix like this. Hope it might help.

Comment: Wow nice thank you very much! But there was another mistake on my side. It has to be somthing like "public-read" instead of "public".

Answer (score 0):

POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: destinationBucket.s3.amazonaws.com
User-Agent: browser_data
Accept: file_types
Accept-Language: Regions
Accept-Encoding: encoding
Accept-Charset: character_set
Keep-Alive: 300
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=9431149156168
Content-Length: length

--9431149156168
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"

acl
--9431149156168
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="success_action_redirect"

success_redirect
--9431149156168
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Content-Type"

content_type
--9431149156168
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="x-amz-meta-uuid"

uuid
--9431149156168
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="x-amz-meta-tag"

metadata
--9431149156168
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="AWSAccessKeyId"

access-key-id
--9431149156168
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Policy"

encoded_policy
--9431149156168
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Signature"

signature=
--9431149156168
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="MyFilename.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

file_content
--9431149156168
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit"

Upload to Amazon S3
--9431149156168--

How to cerate post request in java?